# jasper ireport basic functionality

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am new to JasperReports and iReport and I am sturggling to get the most basic example up and running.  I'm trying to read input from a .xls file and put it into a table using iReport.  Eventually, I want to read from a database, and transform the data in a meaningful way but for now I just want to view what I am reading and I can't get that going.  First, if I just drag and drop my Field into the template, $F{Account}, I would expect to see the list of values for that field name (as I do when I preview my "query").  However, if that is all I do and then preview, I see the first account number in my input xls, and then 50 pages of empty white space.  Why would this be?

Next, if I create a basic table, I am getting an error

`Error filling print... null 
java.lang.NullPointerException      at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.util.TableUtil.isSortableAndFilterable(TableUtil.java:344)    ... 
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...`

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Also, I should note, I did download JasperReports but I'm wondering if I need to somehow connect iReport to those classes.  I saw a way to do it in the Netbeans plugin but I'm just trying to use the iReport GUI

Comment: "I did download Jasper" If you mean "JasperReports" then you should write that. "Jasper" is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table component is great. But it's harder to use than it should be. Take a look at this [Table Component tutorial](http://www.jaspersoft.com/scorm_data/EnablingReportInteractivitywiththeTableComponent_3496/data/execute) to learn how to use it.

For the first part of your question you don't give enough information for anyone to know. My guess is that you put the field into the Title band rather than the Detail band.

Comment: Wow, you are right!  Can you explain to me more about the bands?  I figured I could essentially do anything I wanted in any of the bands but I suppose that is not true.  My goal is to end up with two tables (one on top of another), formatted a specific way.  What do I need to do that?  Thank you so much, after struggling with this all day and looking up every article that exists on the matter I can't tell you how happy I am to just see some data in the preview pane :-)